# Why Does My PHP Code Cut my Footer off?

Tags: php

Does Anyone Know Why this PHP Code cuts my footer off I want it to say login to the user when not logged in and not display the content and when they are logged in then it will display the content . The footer Appears when logged in but when not logged in it goes.Thanks In Advance

```
<div align="center">
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['user']) 
    { 

    echo "<a href=\"/login\" target=\"_blank\">Please Login First!</a>";
    exit(); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the php `exit();` function, this is the reason for cutting off the footer. and also you need to check the session value using `isset($_SESSION['user'])`

it should be,

```
    <div align="center">
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
        { 
           echo "<a href=\"/login\" target=\"_blank\">Please Login First!</a>"; 

        }else{
           // your content here 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ok, I have Removed exit(); and now it is displaying the content when not logged in and its also saying login.

Comment: @user3021550 , did you added this code `isset($_SESSION['user'])` ? please check my answer

Comment: Yes , I did add that.

Comment: You need include the remining stuff in else part.

Answer (score 0):

The exit(); kills the execution of any php code that appears after it

Answer (score 0):

`exit();` will stop any more of the script being executed, including your footer code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exit()` from your code... exit() will terminate your script page so... it's not rendering your footer